# Stream API exception pattern

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I've been using Java Stream API for 2 years. But every time I'm using it, a question comes to my mind, how do I treat checked exceptions?

One thing used to do is to convert them to unchecked, but I see this as a not healthy behavior since I'm changing the natural state of the exception.

Is there any patterns or good practices treating those kind of exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.oreilly.com/ideas/handling-checked-exceptions-in-java-streams) page you have these options :

1. Add a try/catch block to the lambda expression
2. Create an extracted
   method
3. Write a wrapper method that
   catches checked exceptions and rethrows them as unchecked

Maybe number 2 works for you? Log the exception in the try/catch of an extracted method.

Comment: Another option is writing your own functional interface class, with a method that throws the exception in question.